# Calculate channel capacity of general channel under constraint

Tags: entropy, probability-distributions, pr.probability, it.information-theory

Given a conditional distribution $P_{Y\mid X}$ I'd like to find the prior distribution $P_X$ that maximizes the mutual information $I(X;Y)$ with $P_Y(y)=\int P_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)P_X(x) \, \text{d}x$ (this corresponds to finding the channel capacity $C(X;Y):=\max_{P_X}I(X;Y)$) subject to the constraint $E_{P_X}[-\log(X)]=a$.

In my particular case, $P_{Y\mid X}$ is a Bernoulli distribution with $X$ as its parameter and I'm looking for a distribution over the parameter.

My intuition would tell me this should be some Beta-distribution (something like $\text{Beta}(1/a,1)$?!) in my particular case, but I don't know how to approach such a problem, much less in the general case.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What (and why) is the constraint $E[-\log(X)]=a$?

Comment: Sorry, $E[-\log(X)]$ means the expected value of the random variable $X':=-\log(X)$.

It's a little bit complicated to explain where this constraint comes from.  In my particular case it's because the above stuff is a discrete approximization of a poisson process, where "heads" are thrown at a varying rate R. If time is discretized into little bins, this gives, for each of those bins, the probability $X$ to have no "heads" in that bin where $X = \exp(-R)$. The expected value of the rate $E[R]=E[-\log(X)]=a$ is fixed.

If the constraint is the problem, $E[X]=a$ would also be ok.

Comment: What is the range of $X$ (because you are saying $P_{Y|X}$ is Bernoulli with parameter $X$)?

Comment: Sorry, I perhaps was a bit too unspecific there.
$P_{Y|X}{Y=1|X=x}=x$ and $P_{Y|X}(Y=0|X=x)=(1-X)$ where $Y\in\{0,1\}$ and $X\in[0;1]$.


Comment: wupps, should've been $P_{Y|X}(Y=1|X=x)=x$., ofc.

Comment: If your underlying question is about the information theory of Poisson processes, you might find ["The Exponential Distribution in Information Theory"](http://www.princeton.edu/~verdu/reprints/Verdu.Jan.96.pdf?q=tilde/verdu/reprints/Verdu.Jan.96.pdf) (by Verdu, 1996) pretty interesting.  One gets the feeling that every tight bound in information theory can be viewed as the non-negativity of some KL divergence.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to the special case of $a=0.5$ under the less restrictive case $E[X]=a$.
This case is trivial and is solved by $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=0.5$ in which the channel capacity is one which is the maximal value for your channel.